# Reallocating 2D arrays on C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, realloc

lets say i have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int **a; //Global Variable
int main()
{
   n=5;
   a = new int*[n];
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
   a[i] = new int[n] ;
}
```

is there any realloc() method to increase the row size? (**column size is fixed**)
I mean if the row size is 5 then i wanna make it 6 not much more, just +1.
I use

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   counter++;
   a[i] = (int *) realloc(a[i],counter*sizeof(int));
}
```

but i think something is wrong....

Edit: please don't advise any vector or sth like that.. Cuz i need my array as global.

Comment: "Cuz i need my array as global." What does it have to do with anything?

Comment: The thing that is wrong is that [you are using pointers](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) (slides by Konrad Rudolph). `std::vector` objects can also be global.

Comment: @daknok_t u advise me not to use pointers but the coloumn size of my array will be inputted from keyboard. so i have to code `a= new int` stuff. if you know any method to define vector object sizeless, please tell me :)

Comment: @Who Cares [`vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) is what you want. Example: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a; int main() { ... a.reserve(n); ... }`

Comment: @daknok_t can u give me more information about that? For ex, 1) how can I define two dimensional like a.reserve(m,n)? 2)how can i add a new "row" not a coloumn, the coloumn size will be the variable which been inputted from keyboard and will never change. Jut add a row.

Answer (score 4):

`realloc` only works when you allocated with `malloc`. If you used `new`, you'll have to `delete` and then use `new` again (or just use something like a `std::vector`).

EDIT: Since you asked for an example of how to use `malloc`:

```
a = new int*[n];
```

would become

```
a = (int **) malloc (n * sizeof (int *));
```

and

```
a[i] = new int[n] ;
```

would become

```
a[i] = (int *) malloc (n * sizeof (int));
```

Comment: so how can I define my array with malloc ? Can you give me and example for two dimensionals?

Comment: I did `a = (int **) malloc(0 * sizeof(int));` then in a for loop `a[i]=(int *) malloc(0 * sizeof(int));`. but it is still same... it runs realloc command just for once. then segmentation fault...

Comment: still realloc() doesn't work. actually im confused. `a[i] = (int *) realloc(a[i],counter*sizeof(int));` This is in a for-loop 0 to n

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own routine to resize the array.

If you want a resized block with size N

1. allocate (new) the new size N
2. copy old array/block to this newly allocated array/block
3. free the old array (delete)

To avoid calling this routine again and again, better preallocate a large chunk, the size of chunk will be determined by the need of your application, and should be such which avoid resizing the array a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No!**

C++ memory management does not contain functionality for reallocating/resizing allocated memory. You would have to implement such a thing yourself using new/copy/delete semantics

Comment: Actually, the vector’s `reserve` is functionally indistinguishable from `realloc`, albeit on a higher level.

Comment: Thats not true - reserve does not free unused (but allocated) memory, as realloc would. But you are right considering the fact that all STL container resize dynamically. Edited my post.

Comment: That’s why I said “on a higher level”. `reserve` makes sure that large memory blocks are reserved so that `push_back` can access it without having to move memory to a different allocation block. So in fact, `push_back` (not `reserve`) behaves like `realloc`.